# How to increase the line height between the lines of the titles only in a publication

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I have the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1.3in, bottom=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

 \title{
 \textbf{This is the title of the paper that I will publish soon to get my degree in 
 mathematics}
 }
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I need to increase the line height (the line spacing) between the lines of the title only. How can I achieve this ?!.

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

`\setstretch` from the `setspace` package might help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}
\begin{document}

 \title{\setstretch{2}
 \textbf{This is the title of the paper that I will publish soon to get my degree in 
 mathematics}
 }
\maketitle
Just to show that normal text is not affected:
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]